# How Can I convert a uploaded pptx/ppt file to XML format in C# using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml

I have an application which allows uploading a ppt/pptx file. I want to convert the presentation file to equivalent XML format.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: what is `equivalent XML format`?

Comment: I have used openxml to read the slides. But I want the contents in XML format and not in text format. Is it possible to get slides in XML format.

Answer (score 2):

A pptx file is essentially a zip file, renamed to pptx. If you rename and extract the content you can find the xml document.

With ppt you have more problem as it is proprietary to Microsoft and may not even be publicly documented. Office automation would most probably work, but rather complicated.

Comment: How can we get the xml programmatically. The conversion is performed in the backend after the file is uploaded.

Comment: Unzip the content any way you feel comfortable and read the relevant files.